# trigger a middleware function on second attempt and updward

Tags: node.js, react-native

I have a mobile OTP route in NodeJs, and I want to protect this route by adding reCaptcha in my react-native FE application.

My question is, how do I detect if this is the user second attempt calling the API and how do I trigger the reCaptcha validation `ONLY` if 2 or more attempts.

Thank you, I appreciate your time.

Comment: You will need some sort of server-side session to keep track of which clients have passed captcha (and then the API users has to supply the cookie or sessionID that they received after the first call that passed the captcha).  You can then set an expiration on the session.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to make a server-side call to the reCaptcha API to validate the user's response.

example:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

async function validateRecaptcha(response) {
  const secret = 'your-secret-key';
  const url = `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=${secret}&response=${response}`;
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const json = await res.json();
  return json.success;
}
```

Comment: I did that, but my problem is I need to check if it's the user 2nd time requesting the API. and I don't know how to check for that